# create corner in BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android

how can i create corner in top of dialog as AppCompatDialog
My Code is

```
final AppCompatDialog dialog;
dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(v);
        dialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        dialog.create();
```

can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a drawable like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
     android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
     android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
   <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</shape>
```

and apply this drawable as bottomsheet background

```
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet_dialog</item>
</style>
```

and set this theme to bottom sheet

Comment: how set "BottomSheet" dialog style in my "dialog" var

Comment: new Dialog(context,R.style.BottomSheet);